# Improving with Regex Exercises

Tags: regex

Currently i am reading a book Regular Expressions. The book is very very detailed. Although it gives examples while explaning the subjects it is hard to learn without doing a good amount of exercises/practices.

So, can you suggest a site, a book, a place for regex exercises, so that i can solve them and help myself to absorb regexes while reading the book?

Comment: yes, it's called stack overflow :), just follow the regex tag and answer as many as you can... I reckon there are about half a thousand questions per day related to regexes. (the tag has 36000 questions so far)

Comment: You really don't need book on everything. RegEx is just a tool and in my experience you learn it by experience. Sometime when you will really need RegExes you can test and learn them (or ask on SO). I see people seeing a good book on learning Yii but I think its best to learn it from the docs.

Comment: A fun way to test your regular expression skills is with Regex Golf - https://regex.alf.nu/

Comment: Look at https://www.regular-expressions.info for lerning about RegExp

Comment: Look at https://regexcrossword.com for traning some cases of RegExp

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Zed Shaw's [Learn Regex the Hard Way](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/). It's free and the author provides a hands on way to incrementally learn the topic through exercises.

After that, you can go back to your current reading or move on to [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) if you want to dive into more details, or the [Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689) for problems and solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Python try this](http://pythex.org/)

or [General purpose regex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: that link is dead

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson , Thanks, edited

Answer (score 3):

You can tinker with regular expressions interactively with the tools at http://regexpal.com and http://www.regextester.com.  The user-contributed regexes at the Regular Expressions Library (http://www.regexlib.com) are somewhat of a curate's egg, but you can use it to see how other people attack a particular problem.

Comment: for use of "curate's egg"

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the [Regular Expressions Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596520694.do). It contains a lot of typical, practical tasks for regular expressions and explains the suggested solutions for these tasks.

So if you don't read the solution right away, you can see what you can come up with and compare your result to what the masters (Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan) would do.

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386325/where-can-i-find-a-collection-regular-expression-exercises-for-perl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856804/exercises-for-regular-expressions), and googling brought me to [this](http://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/extra_regexps.html) page.
I would personally advice you to challenge yourself. For example; grab a random website, look at the source code and try to write a regular expression that returns all `src` attributes of an `img` element. Just be creative with useless challenges, I believe you can come up with enough of them.

When I wanted to improve my regular expression skills I wrote a chatbot that was capable of interpreting your answer in different ways to find the information it wanted. I also wrote an interpreter for a scripting language that consisted of instructions like `Create a new confirm dialog, with the text "Are you sure you want to do this?".`. Be creative and challenge yourself.

Looking at questions about regular expressions here at stackoverflow is a good idea too. You can try to solve the problems, and if they're already answered you can look at the answers and compare them with yours.